# open firefox multifox window from javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I want to open multiple Firefox profiles. I use Multifox for this, but now I want to open a webpage with specific profile. I can do it manually in Multifox but I want to do it from Javascript .

let's say I have this function in my web page

```
function openProf (profile_number,webpage){


}
```

If I  want to open Facebook in multifox 10th profile window I can call

```
openProf(10,"www.facebook.com");
```

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Hi Mike, how did you code this? I see the answer below different from what you are asking. I also wanted to do this to automate my bumping trade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm');
var exe = FileUtils.getFile('XREExeF', []); //this gives path to executable
var process = Cc['@mozilla.org/process/util;1'].createInstance(Ci.nsIProcess);
process.init(exe);
var args = ['-P', 'YOUR_PROFILE_NAME_HERE', '-no-remote', 'http://www.bing.com/'];
process.run(false, args, args.length);
```

Comment: sir where i put this code?is this js? or addon script?

Comment: Put it in same place you put the `openProf(10,"www.facebook.com");`. You can run this from scratchpad. Press Shift + F4. Enable developer preferences (or onstall [DevPrefs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/devprefs/)) and then in menubar of scratchpad window, go to "Environment" menu and select "Browser". Then copy and paste this code and run it. But make sure to update it with the name of the profile you want to launch.